# Is there attribute for proxing instead of serialzing for remote objects properties in .NET Remoting?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-remoting

I have a class for remoting (name it RemoteClass). It has property Other of class OtherClass. By default, client has a proxy of RemoteClass object and a serialized copy of OtherClass after calling property Other. I want that client recieve a proxy for OtherClass too after calling property Other. Do not suggest me to separate RemoteClass and OtherClass, because this solution is unacceptable. My question is: May I to do what I want with .NET Remoting or It is better to use WCF instead (Can WCF help me at all?). Thanks for advice and any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using Serializable attribute, make your OtherClass inherit from MarshalByRefObject.